# My SQL Full Text search for character by character

Tags: mysql, sql, search, select, character

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `title` varchar(65) default NULL,
  `topic` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `author` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `ondate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `body` text NOT NULL,
);
```

I add an index upon it with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(title,body);
```

When i select a query as follows i want the results if the title has the words like
'cvs','cvsssh','cvsrepository'

```
SELECT id,title FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST('cvs');
```

But it is returning only one row that is with cvs.
It is doing word match i want character match

please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Indu

Comment: could you please explain in detail, what do you exactly mean by 'i want character match'? You want the query to return all records, where there is a character 'c' or character 's' or character 'v' in the `title`?

Comment: Where ever "cvs" is there it should return that record

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the like operator instead?

e.g.:

```
SELECT id,title 
FROM articles 
WHERE title like '%cvs%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Actually i already used like but due to performance issues i moved to match against

Answer (score 0):

It Should be like this :-

```
SELECT id,title FROM articles WHERE title like 'cvs%';
```

This will give you output which starts from csv.. characters.

If you use **'%cvs%'**  then it will give you output which contains cvs

Comment: indeed, i wasn't sure if just those 3 words were searched for, or if that was just an example, thus i used the most generic one.
Also note: putting "%" as first element in the like search string will reduce the performance of the query, so use 'xyz%' instead of '%xyz%' whenever possible.